# AddRefitClient DryIoc and IServiceProvider on Prism for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, refit, httpclientfactory

I am trying to follow [DryIoc and IServiceProvider on Prism for Xamarin.Forms (DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078277/dryioc-and-iserviceprovider-on-prism-for-xamarin-forms-dryioc-microsoft-depende) however I am using RefitClient for `IHttpClientFactory`

```
containerRegistry.RegisterServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<HttpLoggingHandler>();
                services.AddTransient<AuthorizationDelegatingHandler>();

                services.AddRefitClient<IMyApi>()
                    .ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
                        c.BaseAddress =
                            new Uri(apiBaseUrl))
                    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthorizationDelegatingHandler>()
                    .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpLoggingHandler>()
                    .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
                    {
                        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300),
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600),
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(800)
                    }))
                    .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(
                        p => p.CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
            });
```

I have added

`protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension() => PrismContainerExtension.Current;`

When I try to make a request with IMyApi.

```
BaseAddress must be set on the HttpClient instance
  at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2[T,TBody].<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00030] in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:236
```

Comment: Hi there, did you manage to get this working? Trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I personally had to deal with all of that and ended up by creating [Apizr](https://github.com/Respawnsive/Apizr) where auth and logging handlers are built in, policies are resolved from registry and many more features like connectivity test, caching or prioritizing. If it could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Unity rather than Dryloc but the solution is the same.

The key seems very much to depend on installing the correct packages. Install **ONLY** these:

**Prism.Forms.Extended**

**Prism.Unity.Extensions**

> ```
> protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
> {
>     //Omitted Code
>
>     containerRegistry.RegisterServices(serviceCollection =>
>     {
>         serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IApiService, ApiService>(client =>
>         {
>             client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Your Address Here");
>         });
>     });
> }
> ```

> ```
> public class ApiService : IApiService
> {
>     Func<IApi> _createClient;
>
>     public ApiService(HttpClient client)
>     {
>         _createClient = () => 
>         {
>             return RestService.For<IApi>(client, new RefitSettings
>             {
>                 ContentSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer()
>             });
>         }
>     }
>
>     public IApi GetApi()
>     {
>         return new Lazy<IApi>(() => _createClient()).Value;
>     }
> }
> ```

In part also provided by this post:

https://xamgirl.com/consuming-restful-web-service-xamarin-forms-using-refit-part-2/